# Concatenate item from list to two strings

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a list that contains strings which I am trying to plug into a base URL. My attempt at list comprehensions has come up short however and I can't figure out why. Here is my code, which throws the error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

```
input_tokens = self.token_input.GetValue()
token_list = [input_tokens.split('\n')]

url_front = 'https://www.example.com/foo.cgi?token='
url_back = '&user=bar%40email.com'

url = [url_front + s + url_back for s in token_list]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
token_list = [input_tokens.split('\n')]
```

It should be:

```
token_list = input_tokens.split('\n')
```

With the brackets, you are building a list with a single element (which is another list in this case).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized token_list as a list of lists by enclosing input_tokens.split('\n') in square brackets.  Remove them and split() will return a 1-dimensional list that you can comprehend with your list comprehension.

If input_tokens = "one\ntwo\nthree", then token_list is being initialized as [["one","two","three"]].